# NestJS & Passport - Setting response headers in guard

Tags: authentication, passport.js, nestjs, passport-local

in my *NestJS application* I'm using the *local passport strategy* to secure the login route which then returns a jwt. This process is working **properly**.

Now I implemented logic in my local-strategy to **prevent brute-force** (in addition to the overall rate limit in main.ts) as described [here](https://gist.github.com/animir/dc59b9da82494437f0a6009589e427f6). When I throw a TooManyRequests HttpException I also want to set the 'Retry-After' header to be able to give the user helpful information in the frontend. But **I don't have access to the response object in the guard**. I tried to implement an interceptor which did not help. In addition I only have access to the calculated value for 'Retry-after' in my local strategy, as the value is calculated there.

What's the right approach to set this header? Here's my code which is not working properly yet.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

private maxWrongAttemptsByIpPerDay = 100;
private maxConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp = 5;

private  limiterSlowBruteByIp = new RateLimiterMongo({
    storeClient: this.connection,
    keyPrefix: 'login_fail_ip_per_day',
    points: this.maxWrongAttemptsByIpPerDay,
    duration: 60 * 60 * 24,
    blockDuration: 60 * 60 * 24, // Block for 1 day, if 100 wrong attempts per day
})

public limiterConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp = new RateLimiterMongo({
    storeClient: this.connection,
    keyPrefix: 'login_fail_consecutive_username_and_ip',
    points: this.maxConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp,
    duration: 60 * 60 * 24 * 90, // Store number for 90 days since first fail
    blockDuration: 60 * 60 // Block for 1 hour
})

constructor(private authService: AuthService, @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection) {
    super({passReqToCallback: true});
}

async validate(req: Request, username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {

    const usernameIpKey = this.authService.getUsernameIPkey(username, req['ip'])

    const [resUsernameAndIp, resSlowByIp] = await Promise.all([
        this.limiterConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp.get(usernameIpKey),
        this.limiterSlowBruteByIp.get(req['ip'])
    ]);

    let retrySecs = 0;

    // Check if IP or Username + IP is already blocked
    if (resSlowByIp !== null && resSlowByIp.consumedPoints > this.maxWrongAttemptsByIpPerDay) {
        retrySecs = Math.round(resSlowByIp.msBeforeNext / 1000) || 1;
    } else if (resUsernameAndIp !== null && resUsernameAndIp.consumedPoints > this.maxConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp) {
        retrySecs = Math.round(resUsernameAndIp.msBeforeNext / 1000) || 1;
    }

    if (retrySecs > 0) {
        // res.set('Retry-After', String(retrySecs));
        throw new HttpException('Too many requests', HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
    } else {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
        if (!user) {
            // Consume 1 point from limiters on wrong attempt and block if limits reached
            try {
                const promises = [this.limiterSlowBruteByIp.consume(req['ip'])];
                if (!user) {
                    // Count failed attempts by Username + IP only for registered users
                    promises.push(this.limiterConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp.consume(usernameIpKey));
                }

                await promises;

                throw new UnauthorizedException();

            } catch (rlRejected) {
                if (rlRejected instanceof Error) {
                    throw rlRejected;
                } else {
                    // res.set('Retry-After', String(Math.round(rlRejected.msBeforeNext / 1000) || 1));
                    throw new HttpException('Too many requests', HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (resUsernameAndIp !== null && resUsernameAndIp.consumedPoints > 0) {
                // Reset on successful authorisation
                await this.limiterConsecutiveFailsByUsernameAndIp.delete(usernameIpKey);
            }

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of options you have instead of using the strategy as you're currently doing.

1. like you said, in a **guard** throw the exception where you have access to the `ExecutionContext` so you can `context.switchToHttp().getResponse()` for the response object and be able to set headers as needed (you're currently **trying** to do this in a **strategy** file)
2. Use a package like [nestjs-throttler](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-throttler) and use its decorators to help with setting up rate limiting